# createSwitchNavigator - TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I got this error message when trying to insert `createSwitchNavigator()` into `createAppContainer()`.

```
TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
```

My code - router.js

```
export const RootNavigator = (signedIn = false) => {
  return createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      SignedIn: {
        screen: SignedIn
      },
      SignedOut: {
        screen: SignedOut
      }
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: signedIn ? "SignedIn" : "SignedOut"
    }
  );
};

export const createRootNavigator = createAppContainer(RootNavigator());
```

index.js

```
import { createRootNavigator } from "./router";

/**/

const Layout = createRootNavigator(signedIn);
```

Reference: https://github.com/datomnurdin/auth-reactnative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to return a *function* to `createAppContainer` but it expects an instance of `create*Navigator`

Either use it as

```
export const RootNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      SignedIn: {
        screen: SignedIn
      },
      SignedOut: {
        screen: SignedOut
      }
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: signedIn ? "SignedIn" : "SignedOut"
    }
  )
```

or

```
export const createRootNavigator = createAppContainer(RootNavigator());
```

### Edit

For calling `createRootNavigator` as a method

```
export function createRootNavigator (signedIn) {
  return createAppContainer(RootNavigator(signedIn));
}
```

**index.js**

```
const Layout = createRootNavigator(signedIn);
```

Comment: already changed it into RootNavigator() but still same. check my updated question.

Comment: I've added a expo [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@pritishvaidya94/auth-flow-v3), with almost similar configs

Comment: I just realized. the issue is not only in the router.js, but also in index.js. I need to called createRootNavigator() in index.js but not successful.

Comment: Updated the answer